# Struggling to implement a labeled x scale using ordinalScale() || scaleBand() (d3 v4)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I remember being able to do this quite easily in v3, but I've decided to give v4 a go recently after a bit of a hiatus and of course a lot has seemed to change, syntax wise at least.

So I thought I would start off with this [example](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#_continuous), without using a time scale for the x axis.

I've been trying to refer to the [d3 scale api docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md), but after trying out various things (`ordinalScale()` & `scaleBand()` mainly) I can only seem to get the first and last items to appear on the x axis.

When generating the line, it also appears to be playing up a bit.

Here is my code;

```
let tData = [{x: 1, y: 5}, {x: 2, y: 10}, {x: 3, y: 15}, {x: 4, y: 20}, {x: 5, y: 25}, {x: 6, y: 30}, {x: 7, y: 35}, {x: 8, y: 40}]

let svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

let y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

let x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1);

let line = d3.line()
    .x((d) => x(d.x))
    .y((d) => y(d.y))


x.domain(d3.extent(tData, ((d) => d.x)));

y.domain(d3.extent(tData, ((d) => d.y)));


g.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .select(".domain")
    .remove();

g.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Price ($)");

g.append("path")
    .datum(tData)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", line);
```

and a Plunk to go with it;

http://plnkr.co/edit/EJqsjhaGNZ8u3PkEgy2l?p=preview

Hope someone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the x axis is a scaleBand, it needs to know about all possible domain "buckets". In [this example of using strings for domain](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/bdf28027e0ce70bd132edc64f1dd7ea4) , all values are identified as the domain values; not just the min and max.

In your code you use:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(tData, ((d) => d.x)));
```

to identify the min and max of the domain.

Instead, try identifying all possible values, using:

```
x.domain(tData.map( function(d) { return d.x; } ));
```